# Using libtorrent with MSVS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, linker, nuget, libtorrent

I installed [libtorrent](http://www.libtorrent.org/) (version 1.0.2) with the NuGet package manager in MSVS 2013. When I run this to see if I can use it:

```
#include <libtorrent\session.hpp>

using libtorrent::session;

int main()
{
//  session ses;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error `error C1021: invalid preprocessor command 'warning'`.

This takes me to `project_source\packages\libtorrent-src.1.0.2\lib\native\libtorrent\include\libtorrent\config.hpp` to a line:

`#warning unknown OS, assuming BSD`

I'm not sure what that's about, I tried changing it to `#error` as per a post on cplusplus.com, but the same error came up. Probably foolishly, I commented that line out to see what happens, and now it's taking me to `project_source\packages\libtorrent-src.1.0.2\lib\native\libtorrent\include\libtorrent\file.hpp` saying that

`error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory`

Any ideas how to fix this? I tried not using NuGet, but I couldn't figure out how to use libtorrent from downloading source. The website wasn't much help to me.

Comment: How do you compile or generate the static library ["libtorrent.lib"] or DLL ["libtorrent.dll"] ? Which version of boost you used ? Did you use OpenSSL ? @Arvid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking in [config.hpp](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/libtorrent-1_0_2/include/libtorrent/config.hpp#L235), the assumption is that the `WIN32` macro is defined on windows. In your case, that appears to not be the case.

Perhaps you could try to change it to test for `_WIN32` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the #warning issue, but there are quite a few more now (I'm trying to run one of the examples from the website), such as: http://i.imgur.com/CzgkgYR.png. Could it be the version I'm using?

Comment: it does look like you somehow are mixing libtorrent versions. in 1.0.2 (which you say the NuGet package has) torrent_status is defined inside torrent_handle.hpp. In a later version (1.1 iirc) that type was moved out into its own header (which it looks like your error is pointing at). In 1.0.2 you shouldn't have that header though. You may want to make sure the source package you downloaded is not intermingled or pointed to by any include paths

Comment: How to create or generate the static library ["libtorrent.lib"] or DLL ["libtorrent.dll"] ? Which version of boost did you used ? Did you use OpenSSL? @Arvid

Comment: appveyor uses boost-1.59 iirc. but any version from within the last 2 or 3 years should work